# Conditional navigation shows 2 fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments **HomeFragment** and **StarterFragment**.To navigate between fragments I use the Navigation Component.The start destination is HomeFragment in which I check if the application is opening for the first time - then I redirect to StarterFragment.The navigation works correctly, BUT before the StarterFragment appears on the screen, I see the HomeFragment for a while.I understand the reason, while I am reading the first opening parameter, at this moment HomeFragment is drawn on the screen. How can I avoid this? In HomeFragment I Do this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val navController = findNavController()
    val userPreferences = UserDataStore(requireContext().dataStore)

    lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        if (userPreferences.userPreferencesFlow.first().isFirstOpening){
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_starterFragment)
        }
    }
}
```